# Determine all the integer solutions to $23x + 39y = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, divisibility

I would like to calculate all the solutions to this equation using Euclides' algorithm and linear combination after finding the GCD. I suppose it's easy, but I'm a beginner.

$23x + 39y = 2$

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions?

Comment: Yes, he's looking at integer solutions. (just his use of the word Greatest Common Divisor -- GCD -- shows it)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361336/how-to-solve-the-diophantine-equation-8x-13y-1571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the euclidean algorithm:

$$23x + 39y = 2$$

We have to find the $\gcd(23,39)$

Therefore,

$$39 = 23*(1) + 16$$
$$23 = 16*(1) + 7$$
$$16 = 7*(2) + 2$$
$$7 = 2*(3) + 1$$
$$2 = 1*(2)$$

so the gcd is $1$.

Now we rewrite:

$$1 = 7 - 3*(2)$$
$$1 = 7-3*(16-7*(2))$$
$$1 = 7*(7) - 3*(16)$$
$$1 = 7*(23-16) - 3*(16)$$
$$1 = 7*(23)  - 10*(16)$$
$$1 = 7*(23)  - 10*(39-23)$$
$$1 = 17*(23)  - 10*(39)$$
So we multiply by $2$, since we get our orignial equation now:

$$2 = 34*(23)  - 20*(39)$$

So one solution can be $x = 34$, and $y = -20$

Now generalizing, we find that:

$$x = 34 + \frac{39}{1}n = 34 + 39n$$
$$y = -20 - \frac{23}{1}n = -20 - 23n$$

For all integers $n$.

Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c) for more help:

comment if you have questions