# Find integers x and y with 103x + 113y=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find integers $x$ and $y$ with $103x + 113y=1$

How would you solve this problem? I'm thinking maybe you can use Euclidean Algorithm to solve for the inverse?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361336/how-to-solve-the-diophantine-equation-8x-13y-1571

Comment: You can proceed with Euclidean Algorithm, just as you said.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. One implementation is the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&10&3&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-10&31&-103\\
0&1&-1&11&-34&113\\
113&103&10&3&1&0\\
&&&&{\uparrow}
\end{array}
$$
The column with the arrow says that
$$
31\cdot113-34\cdot103=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$113y≡1(mod103) $$
$$10y≡1(mod103)$$
$$10y≡1+309(mod103)$$
$$y≡31(mod103)$$
Hence $y≡31(mod103).$
It is easy to show that $x≡-34(mod113).$

Answer (score 0):

Applying [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174676/solving-simple-congruences-by-hand/174687#174687) allows us to solve it with simple mental arithmetic

$ 103x\!+\!113y=1\iff$ $ {\rm mod}\ 103\!:\  y\equiv \dfrac{1}{113}\equiv\dfrac{1}{10}\equiv\dfrac{10}{100}\equiv\dfrac{-93}{-3}\equiv 31$

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.