# Integer solutions for equation with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain how wolfram alpha calculates integer solutions for these kind of equations:

$$ m=\frac{681+13973k}{2021} $$

and how can I do this myself on the paper?

Here is a link to the wolfram alpha solution:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=m+%3D+%28681+%2B+13973k%29+%2F+2021

where it shows the integer solution at the bottom.

Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361336/how-to-solve-the-diophantine-equation-8x-13y-1571

Comment: thanks for pointing me out in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think they use congruence relation and Euclidean procedure for finding gcd (greatest common divisor).